# Insufficient privileges assigning Azure Active Directory premissions to an MSI enabled Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

We have two azure resources in the same directory.  A webAPI set of APIs behind Azure API Management and an Azure Function.  We want the azure function to be able to call the APIs.  We've enabled MSI on the azure function as described in [How to use managed identities for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity).  We've created an App Registration in AAD for the API, created a role permission to be accessed.  Following [Calling your APIs with Azure AD Managed Service Identity using application permissions](https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions) we run into errors attempting to assign the permission/role to the azure function:
in powershell:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId 8XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX -Id 3XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX -PrincipalId 8XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX -ResourceId 9XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId 8XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewServ
   icePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
```

is giving us a permission error, even when an AAD Admin (member of AAD DC Administrators I think) runs it.  Has anyone run into this before?  Why is this throwing a permissions error?  We have verified that the ids are correct with 3 different people.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're probably facing is that, despite naming your app registration the same thing as your MSI-enabled app, the two end up representing different service principals in AAD. [Using app registrations with MSI isn't currently supported.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51792016/31299)

Try running the powershell commands using the object id of the MSI identity instead. I was able to get this to work, and granted my MSI-enabled app access to the Graph Api.

Here is the PS I used to assign the GraphApi roles my function app required:

```
$functionAppName = "My-FANCY-FUNC"

$context = Get-AzureRmContext -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #this lets you search AAD for func

if(!$context){
    $login = Connect-AzureRmAccount  | Out-Null
    Connect-AzureAD #needed this for Graph API
    $context = $login
} else { Write-Host "Login session already established for " $context.Subscription.SubscriptionName }

#get the SP associated with the MSI
$MSIPrincipal = Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString $functionAppName | Where-Object DisplayName -eq $functionAppName

#get the SP associatesd with the MS Graph
$graph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -match "Microsoft Graph" }

#find the target app roles in the graph
$targetRoles = $graph.AppRoles | Where-Object Value -in "Group.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All"

#iterate throgh the known roles and add the MSI SP to them
$targetRoles | ForEach-Object {New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -Id $_.Id -PrincipalId $MSIPrincipal.Id -ObjectId $MSIPrincipal.Id -ResourceId $graph.ObjectId}
```

I suspect, based on your question, that this line will return more than one entity:

```
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString $functionAppName | Where-Object DisplayName -eq $functionAppName
```

Deleting your extraneous app registration should clear that up

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, I am passing the values as you indicate:  New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId AzureFunction(MSIPrincipal) -Id AppRole(ID of app role created in manifest of App Registration) -PrincipalId AzureFunction(MSIPrincipal) -ResourceId AzureAPI(AAD Principal)

Comment: just for clarification, the only app registration is for the APIs.  The function is only registered through MSI.

Comment: Can you share the auth parts of the PS script? Are you using Connect-AzureAD or  Connect-AzureRmAccount or both?

Comment: honestly, there was no script.  We had to do this once, so we manually got the IDs we needed for the New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment call that I have above.

Comment: If you just typed that into a console it's not gong to work. You need to auth the session against AAD and Azure. The script I provided will work or will help you understand where the user lacks permission